# Json Schema, take into account unspecified properties

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Is there is any ways to get heads ups about properties which are not described by schema into the standard. For example this schema:

```
{
   "description": "foo and bar", 
   "type": "object", 
    "properties": {
       "foo": {
        "type": "number"
       }, 
       "bar": {
        "type": "string", 
        "enum": [
            "a", 
            "b", 
            "c"
        ]
       }
   }
}
```

Will pass this JSON:

```
{
   "foo": 12345, 
   "bar": "a",
   "baz": 12312
}
```

Although it has `baz` property which is not the part of schema.

UPD: As of now I'm using [tv4](https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4) library.

Comment: You'll have to describe which schema library you are using - there are several.

Comment: Thanks for comment, updated. I have assumptions about the standard itself, although any end implementations which would allow that, would work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Option 1: `additionalProperties` in the schema

If you want to explicitly constrained to the properties listed in a particular `properties` definition, then you can use `additionalProperties: false`.  This will restrict data to only using properties defined in the nearby `properties` entry - in this case, `"foo"` and `"bar"`.

However, use of `additionalProperties` impacts schema extension.  If you (or someone else) extends this schema later (using `allOf`/`$ref`), then the data will still be subject to this schema - so will only be allowed to use `"foo"` and `"bar"`, regardless of definitions elsewhere.

#### Option 2: `banUnknownProperties` flag in tv4

If the kind of complete lock-down is not desired, then you can use the [`banUnknownProperties` flag in tv4 (docs)](https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4#the-banunknownproperties-flag).  Basically, after validation, any properties that were not accounted-for by any schemas are raised as errors.

It was designed for cases when extra properties (including future variations/extensions) are theoretically allowed in the data format, but you want (for testing/warning purposes) to be alerted when extra properties show up where you're not expecting them.

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm the developer of tv4.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for late update, banUnknownProperties is what I was looking for. I've checked docs before asking.

Comment: No problem - I proposed including "ban unknown properties" as an "alternative validation mode" in v5, so you'd get reliable behaviour across tools, but didn't get as much support as I'd hoped.